# Understanding Cassandra Composite keys

Tags: cassandra, cql

I just watched [this youtube video of Patrick McFadin](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HdJlsOZVGwM) on cassandra datamodelling.

There was one table, as follows:

```
create table user_activity_history {
  username varchar,
  interaction_date varchar,
  activity_code varchar,
  detail varchar,
  PRIMARY KEY((username,interaction_date),interaction_time)
);
```

Why is the primary key `((username,interaction_date),interaction_time)`.
How is that different from `(username,interaction_date,interaction_time)`.

Comment: Could you add a link to Patrick McFadin's video?

Comment: Added http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HdJlsOZVGwM&feature=share&list=PLqcm6qE9lgKJzVvwHprow9h7KMpb5hcUU

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The difference is related to the table's `partition_key`. Typically the first element in a PRIMARY KEY is also the partition key - this defines the physical location of the data in the cluster, e.g., by using the following:

```
PRIMARY KEY(username,interaction_date,interaction_time)
```

data inserted into the table will be partitioned (located physically) according to `username`, whereas by using the following:

```
PRIMARY KEY((username,interaction_date),interaction_time)
```

it will be partitioned according to the `username,interaction_date` combination. The advantage of the latter scheme is that data relating to a single `username` can be stored across nodes in the cluster.

There is more details on partition_keys in datastax's CQL documentation on [CREATE TABLE](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.1/webhelp/index.html#cql/cql_reference/create_table_r.html):

> When you use a compound PRIMARY KEY Cassandra treats the first column declared in a definition as the partition key and stores all columns of the row on the same physical node. When you use a composite partition key, Cassandra treats the columns in nested parentheses as partition keys and stores columns of a row on more than one node. You declare a composite 
>   partition key using an extra set of parentheses to define which columns partition the data.